# echo form with onblur onfocus

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to echo a form that contains multiple input fields. I want to use onblur and onfocus (see the conditions below in the code), but the javascript function doesn't work when I echo it with php. Any help to rectify the issue\technical explanations would be appreciated.

```
echo '<form action="file.php" method="post">
<input type="text" style="width: 450px" maxlength="50" value="' . $data . '" name="data" id="data"
onblur="if (this.value == "") {this.value = "data";}"
onfocus="if (this.value == "data") {this.value = "";}" />
<input type="submit">
</form>';
```

Comment: please provide a complete example, with the data you intend to use. In your example it looks like you just want a default value is that correct

Comment: If $data isset then the value will be as specified else it will be null (blank).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to read:

```
echo '<form action="file.php" method="post">
<input type="text" style="width: 450px" maxlength="50" value="' . $data . '" name="data" id="data"
onblur="if (this.value == "") {this.value = "data";}"
onfocus="if (this.value == "data") {this.value = "";}" />
<input type="submit">
</form>';
```

Use the **heredoc** syntax, like so:

```
echo <<< FORM
<form action="file.php" method="post">
<input type="text" style="width: 450px" maxlength="50" value="$data" name="data" id="data" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '$data';}"
onfocus="if (this.value == '$data') {this.value = '';}">
<input type="submit">
</form>
FORM;
```

Note that I swapped some of the double quotes for single quotes because they were nested.

For the event handlers (onfocus and onblur), the outer quotes are double quotes.  These enclose the attribute values.  Within the double quotes any strings must be single quoted to avoid closing the attribute value before it has been completed.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Beat me to it. I think you should emphasize the nested quotes more though.

Comment: Thanks for linking me to the manual as well. I will accept this when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you were trying to achieve with the inline js events. if the value is an empty string on blur it will get the [data-default] value, if the value is the [data-default] value on focus it will be cleared.

in php you should set both the [value] and [data-default] values at the same time.

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'. $data .'" data-default="'. $data . '">';
```

```js
var formInput = document.querySelector('#data');

formInput.addEventListener('focus', function( e ){
  if( this.value === this.dataset['default'] ){
    this.value = '';
  }
}, false );

formInput.addEventListener('blur', function( e ){
  if( this.value === '' ){
    this.value = this.dataset['default'];
  }
}, false );
```

```html
<form action="file.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="data" id="data" value="something" data-default="something" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this as well. Thank you!